# MobaXterm: can't connect with Mosh

Tags: windows, networking, mobaxterm, mosh

I am using MobaXterm v22 to connect to my server via Mosh. It has been working fine so far, but now, I get the output:

```
me@myserver's password:
Starting MOSH server...
      - Local charset   : en_FI
      - Remote charset  : en_FI.UTF-8
      - Remote Server   : myserver
      - Remote Username : me
      - SSH port        : 22
me@myserver's password:

Error starting mosh-server on remote server.
Output of server myserver:

SSH Connection: 87.95.151.16 62720 178.62.234.243 22


MOSH CONNECT 60001 tqOLinfy3Gtm6sHL7qEr/A

mosh-server (mosh 1.3.2) [build mosh 1.3.2]
Copyright 2012 Keith Winstein <mosh-devel@mit.edu>
License GPLv3+: GNU GPL version 3 or later <http://gnu.org/licenses/gpl.html>.
This is free software: you are free to change and redistribute it.
There is NO WARRANTY, to the extent permitted by law.

[mosh-server detached, pid = 5976]

────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────

Session stopped
    - Press <return> to exit tab
    - Press R to restart session
    - Press S to save terminal output to file
```

I can connect with MobaXterm using SSH, and I can connect with the official Mosh client to this same server, but I want to use MobaXterm to connect with Mosh.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, this problem no longer appears with the MobaXterm 22.1_preview5 version: https://mobaxterm.mobatek.net/preview.html

Answer (score 0):

Mosh still doesn't work even with the release version 22.1 for me.

However there is a workaround to still use it in mobaxterm:

1. Install mosh with the MobApt package manager if not already there
2. SSH into the server and run `mosh-server` to get your connection credentials
3. Open a Shell tab and run

`MOSH_KEY=YOUR_KEY_FROM_THE_PREVIOUS_STEP mosh-client HOST-IP PORT`

(e.g. `MOSH_KEY=foobarbaz mosh-client 10.0.0.1 60001`)

Don't wait for too long between step 2 and step 3 as mosh will automatically shut down if you don't connect quick enough.